# why doesn't this speech recognition code work?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

So this simple thing doesn't work, the program just keeps on listening forever

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r1 = sr.Recognizer()
r2 = sr.Recognizer()
r3 = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('speak now')
    audio = r1.listen(source)

    try:
        text = r1.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said: {}'.format(text))
    except:
        print('Sorry couldn not recognize your voice')
```

Comment: You didn't write any code to timeout/end the program

Comment: @Phoenix can you enlighten me on this? what should I write to stop the listening ?